# Узнать путь к файлу

Tags: файлы, java

Доброго времени суток! Как узнать путь к файлу? То-есть внутри класса узнать путь к нему

Comment: Код класса приведите.

Comment: Смотрите на SO: [How to get the path of a running jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849255/276994).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В статическом контектсе следующий код вернет `URL` до места, где находится данный класс.
Очевидно, что имя файла есть `Prb.class`.

```
public class Prb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Prb.class.getResource(""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.javarush.test.level03.lesson06.task04;

```
/* Путь к файлу java.exe
Выведи на экран текст: полное имя файла java.exe из установленного пакета java
*/

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String s = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_67\\bin\\java.exe";
        System.out.println(s); //Напишите тут ваш код

    }
}
```

не пропускает